# SFDX commands not able to work in VS Code

Tags: sfdx-plugin, sfdx-error

SFX command is not able to load or use any one of them and throws the following error

```
Command 'SFDX: Authorize an Org' resulted in an error (command 'sfdx.force.auth.web.login' not found)
```

[image]

I tried to update SFDX by this command **sfdx update**  and restart VS Code multiple times with no luck.

Comment: What is your vscode extension pack for Salesforce version?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava v52.17.0

Comment: Are you already set default browser for your computer? Because some time if you not ser default browser, it's also cause this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried too many steps that have been mentioned on the internet such as:
1-sfdx update.
2-reinstall sfdx cli plugin.
3-restart VS code.
4-and I also I tried to use commands instead of VS code.

but all of previous steps didn't work until I deleted the usernames.json files in the following path:

```
C:\Users\myUser\.sfdx
```

(i.e you will find each user name that you used to login as a .json file)

Answer (score -2):

sfdx force:auth:web:login

Not dot notation

Comment: The asker is using the Visual Studio Code command palette, not the command line.